# Is it correct to see protractor cucumber tests pass when I cannot see the browser doing any interactions?

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, cucumber

I am new to protractor cucumber. I have written the feature below. When I launch `protractor protractor.conf.js`, the browser opens and then closes like immediately and then displays that my tests passed. Is this correct testing functionality? I thought I need to see browser interactions of the login process.

> ```
> Scenario: Open the browser and login
>     Given I am on the login page
>     When I should be able to login with my credentials
>     When I logout
>     Then I should be able to see login page
> ```
>
> Scenario: Open the browser and login
>
> √ Given I am on the login page
>       √ When I should be able to login with my credentials
>       √ When I logout
>       √ Then I should be able to see login page
>
> login page
>
> 1 scenario (1 passed) 
>   4 steps (4 passed) 
>   0m00.005s

```
this.Given('I am on the login page', function() {

   browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
});

this.When('I should be able to login with my credentials',  function() {
    let inputUsernameField = element(by.css(USERNAME_NAME));
    inputUsernameField.sendKeys(username);
    let inputPasswordField = element(by.css(PASSWORD_NAME));
    inputPasswordField.sendKeys(password);
    element(by.id(LOGIN_BUTTON_ID)).click();
});

this.When('I logout',  function() {

    element(by.className(HAMBERBURGER_MENU_ICON_CLASS)).click();
    element(by.className(LOGOUT_BUTTON_CLASS)).click();
});

this.Then('I should be able to see login page', {timeout:120*1000},function() {

    browser.driver.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($('#login_button')), 5000);
});
```

Below is the protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout: 600000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
  framework: 'custom',
  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  multiCapabilities:
  [
  {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }],

  // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ],
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  ignoreSynchronization: true,
  cucumberOpts: {
    strict: true,
    require: [
              'hooks/reporter/js',
              'specs/*Spec.js'
            ],
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    format: 'json:e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json',
    resultJsonOutputFile: 'e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json'
  },

  onPrepare: function() {

    var chai = require('chai');
    chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
    global.expect = chai.expect;
    global.baseURL = this.baseURL;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.waitForAngular();           
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);  
  },

  onComplete: function() {

    const report = require('multiple-cucumber-html-reporter');

    report.generate({
        jsonDir: 'e2e/reports/',
        reportPath: 'e2e/reports/',

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it fail when the code *doesn't* work?

Comment: Hmm. If I comment out the stuff inside the When `I should be able to login with my credentials`, all the steps still passes

Comment: No, I mean when the code you're *testing* doesn't work. Or when the credentials are wrong, maybe.

Comment: Shouldn't the test fail on step `this.When('I logout')` when I comment out the element interactions inside `this.When('I should be able to login with my credentials',  function()`. The issue I'm having is not seeing the browser load the login page. The browser does open with a blank page and then closes immediately and shows pass for all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I need to use async and await if I'm not passing anything in the function as a callback. This is in **Javascript** syntax not **Typescript**

```
this.Given('I am on the login page', function() {

   browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
});

    this.Then('I should be able to see login page', {timeout:120*1000},function() {

    browser.driver.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($('#login_button')), 5000);
});
```

**Changed to with async/await**

```
this.Given('I am on the login page', async() => {

   await browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
});

this.Then('I should be able to see login page', {timeout:120*1000}, async() => {

    await browser.driver.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($('#login_button')), 5000);
});
```

Comment: Or you can return a promise-like object in each step function.